# Printing from javascript in chrome: how to know printing is done?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

In my chrome browser version 17.0.942.0 winvista the **printdlg is not the usual modal system-printdlg but renderered within the website** itself. So I want to print canvas content as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716756/printing-just-canvas-element-on-a-page). But the code

`window.print();
 window.close();`

wont work, because `window.close` also closes the printdlg. So in chrome `window.close` must be initiated by the user or delayed somehow. Is there a way to know if `window.print` was finished, so that the window can be closed automatically?

Comment: I didn't realise you could override the print dialog, I thought this was an OS generated dialog? Could you attach a screen shot please so we can take a look?

Comment: Imo one cannot overwrite the print dlg, chrome just introduced a new one as standard, which is rendered within the website. Screenshots should show it: [click](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/7715/chromeprint.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not something I've looked at, so not sure if it's possible or not. However if you run into a deadend and you only need it to work in chrome and you have control of the deployment environment (e.g. you know how the printer is setup etc), Google cloud print may have some useful tips http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/docs/overview.html

Comment: Google cloud print looks, as if it could be an interesting alternative, thanks! \*reads\*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this comment on a bug report similar to what you are experiencing:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92107#c31

It seems like `window.print` is async, the workaround is to check for a mouse movement event after the print, which would occur when the print dialog is closed, then you can perform the rest of your actions.

Also see: [Chrome window.print() window.close() results in 'print preview failed'. Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652981/chrome-window-print-window-close-results-in-print-preview-failed-solution)

Answer (score 4):

add this script to your popup print window

```
<script src="/assets/print_window_close.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

contents of print_window_close.js is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        window.close();
    }, 1);

});
```

basically seTimeout is called only when the document is focused which happens only when the overlay print dialog is closed. hence this works exactly the same way you wanted.

Comment: Would you really want setTimeout being run every millisecond?  Perhaps it should be 500?  Also, this causes the original window calling the new window to hang with respect to JS.  All JS functionality on the page no longer works.  I've noticed it with several different approaches to this problem and haven't been able to figure out the core problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use window.onafterprint.
For example:

```
window.onafterprint = function(){console.log('Print finished...')}
```

Then you could find more details in this post: http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/