# onfocus event on body in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a page that I am trying to close after printing.
I am using the following code which works in IE.

```
<body id="sumReportBody" onload="window.print();" onfocus="window.close();">
```

The idea is that when the print dialog closes the focus is on the page and it closes itself.

This does not work in Chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate. [Here's one possible answer to try](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8260640/1896761).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing from javascript in chrome: how to know printing is done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227746/printing-from-javascript-in-chrome-how-to-know-printing-is-done)